# Connect one css-file to several html-pages

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an external CSS file for my homepage. The only problem is that I know how to fix that for one HTML-page, but not for the rest.

On the page "Contact" I have this in the head.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"/>`

But I want to connect the other pages also to this CSS-file.
How do you do it?

Answer (score 4):

Exactly the same way. Between the `<head></head>` tags of each page, put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
```

I often will use the CSS comments to divide up the CSS file into sections, like this:

```
/*   General  */
    .header{ width:50px;etc.}
    .nav {width:50px;etc}

/*  Home Page Only  */
    #mainPic {width:50px;etc}
    #somethingElse {width:50px;etc}

/*  Page 2  */
    .img {width:50px;etc}
    #menu {width:50px;etc}
```

Remember that if you have elements on two pages (two different areas of the same CSS file) that have the same name, the second one will overwrite the first:

```
/*  Home Page Only  */
    #mainPic {width:50px;}
    #somethingElse {width:50px;etc}

/*  Page 2  */
    .img {width:50px;etc}
    #mainPic {width:333px;}
```

In the above example, the #mainPic element on both pages will have a width of 333px. Therefore, only use the same ID or class names for elements that will have the same CSS. If the CSS changes, change one of the names:

```
    #mainPic2 {width:333px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to place that link to the css file in each  of each page to work. A better solution would be to create a separate header page which can then be included into page at the top so you don't have to keep writing the same code over and over.

Comment: That seems like advanced for the OP. You should explain that further.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as a `.css` and link it to any of your html pages like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<name_of_css_file>.css">
```